# Google Charts print size doesn't consider chartArea

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I'm working on a somewhat long-in-the-tooth AngularJS 1.2 application that uses angular-google-charts as a wrapper. I've tried and succeeded at getting the chart to display the way I want it to when I emulate the print media in Chrome Inspector. However, when I actually go to print, the chart is reduced to a 400 x 200 w/h ratio, and the labels start to overlap.
I've used the chartArea options in the chart object to fix the print version of the chart to 400 x 600, with a small offset for the vAxis, and, again, it works when I am developing from the emulated print view. 
I've also attempted to use the [PNG-generating getImageURI() method](https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart/issues/62), which I can resize, but the resolution stays the same - so I get a grainy PNG with labels overlapping.
I've also attempted a callback method to re-set the chartOptions on load, and I'm able to reset the overall size, but I don't see how to do the chartArea with a callback.

```
let resizeChart = {'height': 456, 'width': 678};
$scope.resizeChartPrintOptions = function (chartWrapper) {
    chartWrapper.setOption("height", resizeChart['height']);
    chartWrapper.setOption("width", resizeChart['width']);
    console.log('chartWrapper: ', chartWrapper); // this shows chart size but not chart area
}
```

I'm at a loss for how to debug the print preview, other than to use the Chrome Inspector render emulator, which isn't serving me the way I expected. 
How can I print a Google Chart to the desired size?